# Min-Width not working

Tags: css

I have a topButtonbar which i have put inside a container whose width is 100% so as if in near future i need more buttons more can be added....

My button are inside a container namely TopButtonbar which i have kept at min-width:243px; and floated it on left. The buttons with in it are all floated right so as to make button position just apposite to that of a english version button bar which is floated right and button inside floated left....

My arabic template is adhering the setting of min-Width and float setting when i am runining it on crome and IE while keeping compatibility mode off.... When i am keeping IE Compatibility mode on, the button inside the TopButtonBar are stretching the Topbuttonbar which has min-width of 240px from let to right all along.... this is really apposite what i want....

i have tried the auto property for width but the results are same....

can you tell me how to fix this problem in IE Compatibility Mode.....

Answer (score 0):

It's IE, supporting CSS hasn't ever really been its strong point. Anyway, how about this?
http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx